# Jetpack Compose: How to wrap the height of the parent while having offset content

Tags: android, height, offset, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make the height of the parent which has the background color fit the height of the text content and not the image which has been offset.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .background(Color.Cyan, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .clickable { }
) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(224.dp)
            .align(alignment = Alignment.TopEnd)
            .offset(y = -88.dp, x = 50.dp),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_pray),
        contentDescription = null,
    )
    Box(...)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Resolved the issue by applying IntrinsicSize.Min on the height modifier of the parent:

```
 Box(..., modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min){
    Image(...)
    Box(...)
```

I found it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMKMwh9gZuI&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers